# "No serializer defined for type: System.Collections.HashTable" or "System.ComponentModel.ISite" when using protobuf-net

Tags: c#, protobuf-net

I encountered the following errors when trying to serialize a class in protobuf-net.  The Hashtable contains many different kind of object arrays, so unfortunately I can't use a dictionary.  There are derived types of the ISite, but if the interface itself is part of .NET there isn't much I can do as far as I can tell.

I have looked up some stuff about RuntimeTypeModel, but as as far as I can tell it only applies to custom classes you make. Any guidance would be very much appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: RuntimeTypeModel applies to any type, not only classes you make.

Comment: What is `ISite`? is that an interface? I don't think that's going to work well ... interfaces are implementation, not data. Can you be more specific about what that is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that `Hashtable` doesn't work well is that it **doesn't know what you're going to put in it**. protobuf-net is a contract based serializer; `Hashtable` is essentially a map of `object`-to-`object`. And `object` is **not** a contract - in fact, it is the exact opposite of a contract. by comparison, `Dictionary<int, SomeType>` would work **just fine** (as long as `SomeType` can be used as a contract).

The reason that `ISite` doesn't work is that *presumably* it is an interface. Interfaces represent implementation, not data. As it happens, protobuf-net *does* have some limited support for interface members, but frankly you're better off keeping interfaces away from DTOs (i.e. your data contracts). What type of `ISite` implementation should it create? What data is needed for that? How is the `SomeFunSite : ISite` that you've used meant to be instantiated and wired up to things? Too many questions for a serializer to be involved in. What a serializer wants is: "I'm serializing a `Foo`; `Foo` has 2 integers, a string, and a `Bar` - although there's also the `SuperBar : Bar` subclass that it needs to know about in some cases". That's more than enough problems.

Good contract:

```
[ProtoContract]
public class MyData {
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public Dictionary<int, SomeType> Items {get; } = new Dictionary<int, SomeType>();

    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public SomethingElse Whatever { get;set;}
}
```

Bad contract:

```
[ProtoContract]
public class MyData {
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public Hashtable Items {get; } = new Hashtable();

    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public ISometing Whatever { get;set;}
}
```

*In some cases* it is possibly to configure `RuntimeTypeModel` to understand what you are trying to do, but: not always. It would depend on context; context that I don't have.

---

Edit: minor clarification: `{get;}`-only properties are now supported in the source code, but not in the current NuGet build - basically, don't use that just yet!

---

Here's a runnable example of marking storing similar data:

```
using ProtoBuf;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var obj = new MyData
        {
            Site = new BasicSite { BaseHost = "http://somesite.org" },
            Items =
            {
                {"key 1", SomeType.Create(123) },
                {"key 2", SomeType.Create("abc") },
                {"key 3", SomeType.Create(new Whatever { Id = 456, Name = "def" }) },
            }
        };

        var clone = Serializer.DeepClone(obj);
        Console.WriteLine($"Site: {clone.Site}");
        foreach(var pair in clone.Items)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{pair.Key} = {pair.Value}");
        }
    }
}


[ProtoContract]
class MyData
{
    private readonly Dictionary<string, SomeType> _items
        = new Dictionary<string, SomeType>();
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public Dictionary<string, SomeType> Items => _items;
    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public ISite Site { get; set; }
}

[ProtoContract]
[ProtoInclude(1, typeof(SomeType<int>))]
[ProtoInclude(2, typeof(SomeType<string>))]
[ProtoInclude(3, typeof(SomeType<Whatever>))]
abstract class SomeType
{
    public object Value { get { return UntypedValue; } set { UntypedValue = value; } }
    protected abstract object UntypedValue { get; set; }

    public static SomeType<T> Create<T>(T value) => new SomeType<T> { Value = value };
}
[ProtoContract]
class SomeType<T> : SomeType
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public new T Value { get; set; }
    protected override object UntypedValue { get => Value; set => Value = (T)value; }
    public override string ToString() => Value?.ToString() ?? "";
}
[ProtoContract]
class Whatever
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public override string ToString() => $"{Id}, {Name}";
}
[ProtoContract]
[ProtoInclude(1, typeof(BasicSite))]
interface ISite
{
    void SomeMethod();
}
[ProtoContract]
class BasicSite : ISite
{
    void ISite.SomeMethod() { Console.WriteLine(BaseHost); }
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public string BaseHost { get; set; }
    public override string ToString() => BaseHost;
}
```

Comment: The HashTable like i said is basically a dictionary of <string, object (could be multiple types that are not related to each other)>.

The ISite variable is going to be one of two types derived from the interface, so perhaps I can test it on those two derived types.

Comment: @Varun if the 2 `ISite` implementations are pretty simple, then [ProtoInclude] can probably make it all work. Hard to tell without an example. But "(could be multiple types that are not related to each other)" is **not** a good contract. There *are* ways to represent that in solid contracts, though; for example a common base class that declares multiple known container subclasses. Which can be most conveniently done via `SomeBaseClass` and `SomeDerivedClass<T>` (and declare the various `T` via [ProtoInclude]). Again, would need to see an example to show how to address it.

Comment: @VarunSablok I've added a runnable example into the answer

Comment: A good tip for serialization is that sometimes the objects you serialize are not the objects you deal with throughout the rest of the application. Sometimes you have to build types that are specifically built to handle serialization and deserialization well, and the requirements for these might be completely different from the types you want to use inside your application.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen absolutely; I should have been more explicit about that, it is a central point. My mantra is essentially: by all means try serializing your regular object model, but **the first moment** that it fights back, create a separate model **just for serialization** that fits the chosen serializer, and map between the two things. If you serialize to multiple formats, this may require multiple different serialization models (DTO models).

Comment: So I've determined that the Hashtable can only contain 2 types, but they both have the same fields and methods, so I think I can make a base type that both classes derive from and retool that field into a dictionary.  The ISite stuff, I'm still looking at - but you helped me a lot, so I think I can mark this answer as closed. Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: Also, I'm sure you've heard this a lot, but protobuf-net  blows my mind with how much faster it is compared to the basic BinaryFormatter :)